# Why can't I delay a remove call with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, delay

I would like for a div to fadeOut and then be removed:

```
 $('#div').delay(1000).fadeOut(300);
 $('#div').delay(1300).remove();
```

Unfortunately, this just directly removes the div, with no delays. Why is it that I can't get the remove action to be delayed? What solutions are there?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure `delay` only works for animations.

Comment: delay is meant to be used with animation effects and not jQuery DOM manipulation methods

Comment: `$('#div').delay(1000).fadeOut(300, function(){$(this).remove();});`?

Comment: @Rocket has the answer.   and should probably post his comment as it is a correct answer for this situation.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want the element to be removed after it's done being faded out, you can `fadeOut`'s callback parameter.

```
$('#div').delay(1000).fadeOut(300, function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

`.delay()` only works with methods that go through the animation queue.  Thus, it works for `.fadeOut()` (an animation), but not `.remove()` (not an animation).

To show you how specialized this is, this doesn't delay:

```
$('#div').delay(1000).hide();
```

But, this does:

```
 $('#div').delay(1000).hide(1);
```

Putting a duration on the hide method turns it into an animation which then uses the animation queue, which then works with `.delay()`.

To remove the item with a delay, you can use a `setTimeout()` call:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div').remove();
}, 1300);
```

or get a bit tricky and use a completion function on an animation like this:

```
$('#div').delay(1000).hide(1, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: `hide` still keeps the element in the DOM, whereas `remove` doesn't.

Comment: hmm thanks for your response. Are there delay methods that work with non-animation actions?

Comment: @jay: There's good 'ol `setTimeout`, but other than that, not really.  It works for animations because they're in a queue (and it probably uses `setTimeout` anyway).

Comment: As far as I know, there are no jQuery delay functions that work with operations outside the queue.  You just use setTimeout() for that.  I did add to my answer a way of using a completion function on an animation for doing the remove.  That lets you use `.delay()`.

Comment: @Rocket - read the rest of my answer to see why I was using the .hide() as an example.  I'm just explaining how .delay() works or doesn't work.  Then, I show a couple of examples that do remove the item.

Comment: @jfriend00: Ah, ok :-P It's almost time to leave work and my brain is toast.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
$('#div').delay(1000).fadeOut(300,function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#div').remove()
    } ,1300);

});
```

I think it works as it should. Hope it helps

Comment: Do not pass a string to `setTimeout`, pass a function instead.

Comment: I think the OP wants the element to be removed immediately after the `fadeOut` is done.