# jQuery - delay and fadeout before remove

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a `.delay()` and `.fadeOut()` then `.remove()`

But `delay` and `fadeout` has no effect in `remove`

Here is my code:

```
jQuery("#container").delegate(".remove", "click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = jQuery(this).data('parent');
    jQuery(this).closest('.' + parent).fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).remove();
})
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.REF:http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Thanks I will correct my code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

why not

```
jQuery(this).closest('.' + parent).fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).remove()
});
```

You should make use of the complete callback provided by [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) in this case

```
jQuery("#container").on("click", ".remove", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = jQuery(this), parent = $this.data('parent');
    $this.closest('.' + parent).fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).remove();
})
```

Comment: Can I just replace delegate with on()

Comment: @HowToPlease you need to swap the 1st and 2nd params

Comment: as always your solution is best, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`.remove()` is not in a query nor is it a transition so `.delay()` will not work. Use `setTimeout` instead.

```
jQuery(this).closest('.' + parent).fadeOut(1000, function(){
   setTimeout($(this).remove(), 1000)
});
```

A side note, use `.on()` instead of `.delegate()` with the newer versions of jQuery

Comment: What is "this" here  `jQuery(this)...`?

Comment: `.remove` button class

Comment: @dreamweiver can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Spokey: Why `$(this).closest('.' + parent).remove()` for 1st parameter of `setTimeout`? It must be `$(this).remove()`

Comment: @ABFORCE true, I wasn't very sure. I did add that at first

Comment: @Spokey: I'm sure, it must be `$(this).remove()`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below

```
jQuery("#container").delegate(".remove", "click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = jQuery(this).data('parent');
    //jQuery(this).closest('.' + parent).fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).remove();

    jQuery(this).closest('.' + parent).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
})
```

Read the below **link** to find out about other methods of doing this.

[Why can't I delay a remove call with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100772/why-cant-i-delay-a-remove-call-with-jquery)

## Advice

Try using `.on()` instead of using `.delegate()`

Answer (score 0):

I create simple function for my project. I use Bootstrap alerts, but the last row answer your question:
$('#some-tag').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut('slow',**function(){$(this).remove();}**);

```
 function alertFade(type,message){
    //alerts: info, warning, success, danger
    var $div = $('<div id="addSuccess" class="alert alert-'+type+'">'+message+'</div>');
    $('#alerts').append($('<div id="addSuccess" class="alert alert-'+type+'">'+message+'</div>'));
    $('#alerts').children().fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
}
```